# unity camera should rotate around static point

Tags: unity-game-engine, static, camera, rotation, point

When I press the play button for preview, I want the camera to stay static (rotating around a static point) instread of moving around that point in a fixed radius.

I can't find the correct configuration - does anybody know the setting I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a camera object in unity editor (make sure there is only one camera at that depth level).

   1.1. If you are using a different camera as well, then delete the audio listener component on the new camera.
2. Add MouseLook component to your camera (the script comes as default in unity).

   2.2 If you cannot find the MouseLook script component, then go to Assets->Import Package -> Characters, and select MouseLook.

   Your done, now when you press play you will be able to rotate around with your mouse, but the camera position will be static.